# Can FOSD-transitivity replace the transitivity in utility representation theorem?

Tags: microeconomics, theory, risk

Let $\succsim$ be a complete, non transitivity preference relation. I wonder if FOSD-transitivity implies transitivity.

The primitive is the space of lotteries $p_1,p_2,p_3,...$. We say the preference satisfies FOSD-transitivity if $p_1\succsim p_2 \succsim...\succsim p_n$ implies $p_n$ does not FOSD $p_1$.

I think the answer is no, as we can easily find three lotteries $p,q,r$ such that they don't FOSD each other. Then we let $p\succsim q\succsim r\succsim p$.

However, when finding a specific numeric example, I failed.

Answer (score 2):

Take as example the set of lotteries over the outcomes $(1, 5, 10)$ consider the lotteries $L_1, L_2, L_3$ where,
$$
\Pr(L_1 = 1) = 0.5\\
\Pr(L_1 = 5) = 0\\
\Pr(L_1 = 10) = 0.5
$$

$$
\Pr(L_2 = 1) = 0.1\\
\Pr(L_2 = 5) = 0.9\\
\Pr(L_2 = 10) = 0
$$

$$
\Pr(L_3 = 1) = 0.2\\
\Pr(L_3 = 5) = 0.5\\
\Pr(L_3 = 10) = 0.3
$$

Lottery $L_i$ FOSD $L_j$ if $\Pr(L_i \le x) \le \Pr(L_j \le x)$ for all $x$.

Note that

- $\Pr(L_1 \le 5) = 0.5 < \Pr(L_2 \le 5) = 1$ and $\Pr(L_2 \le 1) = 0.2 < \Pr(L_1 \le 1) = 0.5$, so there is no FOSD between $L_1$ and $L_2$.
- $\Pr(L_2 \le 1) = 0.1 < \Pr(L_3 \le 1) = 0.2$ and $\Pr(L_3 \le 5) = 0.7 < \Pr(L_2 \le 5) = 1$, so there is no FOSD between $L_2$ and $L_3$.
- Finally, $\Pr(L_3 \le 1)  = 0.2 < \Pr(L_1 \le 1) = 0.5$ and $\Pr(L_1 \le 5) = 0.5 < \Pr(L_3 \le 0.5) = 0.7$, so there is no FOSD between $L_1$ and $L_3$.

I think you need lotteries on at least 3 outcomes to get such examples. If there are only two outcomes, the FOSD relation is complete.

Comment: Great answer I verify that it works (finding three lotteries not FOSD each other). Though just one humble cent: lottery usual means a probability distribution of a real interval, say $[0,1]$. What you have here is called simple lottery: the lottery with finite number of outcomes, which is the counterpart of simple random variable.

Comment: May I ask what is the specific preference relation you have in mind for the set of all lotteries?